# TypeError while doing GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Please help me with my model--> [Code](https://pastebin.com/iGN58TtL)

There is an error popping up saying "typeerror: 'int' object is not subscriptable" pls help me resolve my problem.

```py
#Feature Selectioon and Model Creation
 
pipe_logistic = Pipeline([
    ('power_trnf', PowerTransformer()),
    ('best_features', SFS(RandomForestClassifier(), cv=None, floating=False, n_jobs=-1, scoring='accuracy', verbose=10)),
    ('logistic', LogisticRegression(n_jobs=-1))
])
 
params_logistic = {
    'best_features__estimator__n_estimators': [int (x) for x in range(200,  500, 50)],
    'best_features__k_features': [int (x) for x in range(4, 9, 1)],
    'logistic__penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
    'logistic__C': [0.1, 100, 0.01, 10],
    'logistic__solver': ['liblinear'],
    'logistic__max_iter': [int (x) for x in range(100, 400, 50)],
    # 'logistic__l1_ratio': [1.0, 0.01, 0.001, 1.0, None]
}
 
logistic_gs = GridSearchCV(pipe_logistic, params_logistic, verbose=10, n_jobs=-1, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
logistic_gs.fit(X_train, y_train) //error
```

The error msgs are as follows

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mist/Desktop/Project/Supervised Learning/Classification/Diabetes_prediction.py", line 183, in <module>
    logistic_gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

ValueError: 
All the 2880 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2880 fits failed with the following error:
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 273, in _wrap_func_call
    return func()
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 588, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 588, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlxtend/feature_selection/utilities.py", line 110, in _calc_score
    selector.est_.fit(X[:, IDX], y, **fit_params)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 504, in fit
    self.n_classes_ = self.n_classes_[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 732, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 416, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 370, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 353, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 950, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlxtend/feature_selection/sequential_feature_selector.py", line 853, in fit_transform
    self.fit(X, y, groups=groups, **fit_params)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlxtend/feature_selection/sequential_feature_selector.py", line 544, in fit
    k_idx, k_score, cv_scores = self._feature_selector(
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlxtend/feature_selection/sequential_feature_selector.py", line 780, in _feature_selector
    work = parallel(
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1944, in __call__
    return output if self.return_generator else list(output)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1587, in _get_outputs
    yield from self._retrieve()
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1691, in _retrieve
    self._raise_error_fast()
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1726, in _raise_error_fast
    error_job.get_result(self.timeout)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 735, in get_result
    return self._return_or_raise()
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 753, in _return_or_raise
    raise self._result
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried debugging by changing values in the lists inside the params grid but nothing changed. I tried changing the PowerTransformer() to StandardScaler() but nothing changed.